# Custom Notification Layout for jelly bean android

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a custom notification layout. in which i have some buttons . i want to change this play icon to pause when press once. if press again then change pause to play icon.
actually i want to develop a music app . where music control buttons  will be in the notification bar such as play, pause, next etc. that's all

I have done all of this except "change play button to pause when press once. if press again then change pause to play ." How i change a button image after press on notification bar.

Anyone please help me ..

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-jelly-bean-notification-tutorial.html have a look at this good tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just update my notification with changed image play to pause with the same notification id and then it works fine for me...

i just following....

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating

thanks..